Function of non-rendered component is running in rendered component React
I have some routes in my React project. Whenever I switch from a route with a left sidebar component to a route without a left sidebar component, I get an error because of the function in the left sidebar.
Function:
componentDidMount() {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
      var leftsidebar = $("#left-sidebar");
      
      function updateSidebarPosition() {
        var footerTop = $("footer").offset().top;
        var sidebarHeight = leftsidebar.outerHeight();
        var stopPoint = footerTop - sidebarHeight - 54;

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stopPoint) {
          leftsidebar.css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: stopPoint + 54 + "px",
          });
        } else {
          leftsidebar.css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: "56px",
          });
        }
      }

      // Initial call to set up the sidebar position
      updateSidebarPosition();

      // Update sidebar position on scroll using requestAnimationFrame
      var isScrolling = false;
      $(window).on("scroll.updateSidebar", function () {
        if (!isScrolling) {
          isScrolling = true;
          window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            updateSidebarPosition();
            isScrolling = false;
          });
        }
      });

      // Update sidebar position on window resize
      $(window).on("scroll.resize", function () {
        updateSidebarPosition();
      });
    });
  }


In short, the feature of the function is that it changes the position property of the left sidebar when it touches the footer.
But in my /signin route, there is no left sidebar or footer.
My Routes
<Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <MainLayout isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
              <QuestionList />
            </MainLayout>
          }
        />

<Route
          path="/signin"
          element={
            <AuthLayout isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
              <SignIn />
            </AuthLayout>
          }
        />

This is my Layouts
function AuthLayout({ children, isAuthenticated }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navi isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
//////
function MainLayout({ children, isAuthenticated }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navi isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
      <Leftsidebar />
      <div>{children}</div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

Whenever I switch from / urls to /signin and change the size of the page I get the error
The error says TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')
at updateSidebarPosition .
I thought I could fix this problem by checking the presence of the left sidebar to stop the function from running.Like this:
componentDidMount() {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
      var leftsidebar = $("#left-sidebar");
      if(leftsidebar.length > 0){
       //function content
       }

it didn't work

$(window).on("scroll" You set up listeners for the scroll and resize events. Do you have a corresponding spot where you unsubscribe from the events? Ie, in ComponentWillUnmount?

It was enough to remove the events I subscribed to from the window.
componentWillUnmount() {
        $(window).off("scroll.updateSidebar");
        $(window).off("resize.updateSidebar");
      }

